# How to generate (and verify) a digital signature of a limited size in Python?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, hmac

I'm building a trading application that send orders to the market and I would like to insert a unique signature in each order, so their authenticity can be verified later. When creating a new order, the exchange give the possibility to add a `clientId` in which the signature could be inserted.

The problem is that this field is limited to 20 characters, which mean it's not possible to insert the output of a RSA hash.

What would be the best solution to achieve that ? The idea is that orders authenticity can be verified later on with a public key, so without revealing the private key used to generate the signature.

Basically, this is how the desired process would looks like:

```
# Generate a set of keys
private_key, public_key = generate_keys()

# Generate a signature
client_id = sign(private_key)

> print(client_id)
'kdn9l21hr7HYR5Ep32s0'  # 20 characters lenth

# Do stuff is the signature is valid
if check_sign(client_id, public_key):
    
    do_stuff()
```

I have found that the size of the resulting hash (in bytes) of the `BLAKE2` hashing function can be configured, but I think it can't be used as a signature in this case, because the hash can't be verified with a public key - as with RSA signature.

Any recommandations would be greatly appreciated.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#using-different-digest-sizes

Comment: There is no "RSA Hash". You can create a hash or an RSA signatures. But RSA signatures are known to be very large (no matter which hash method you use) as their size is at minimum the size of the key (e.g. RSA 2048bit means the size is at minimum 256 bytes and then encoded to text it gets even longer). There are other signatures like ECDSA but they are still longer than 20 characters. 20 characters means base64 encoded about 15 bytes effectively. In that size you may only place a MAC ("symmetric signature").

Comment: Thanks for the information, I learned that with symetric signature the same key used to generate the MAC is also used to verify.

Comment: That is a major disadvantage of course, but 20 characters are just too small for a real signature. Otherwise you would have to use different server to store the signature and then just use the 20 characters to reference it.

Comment: At the question "What asymetric scheme provides the shortest signature, while being secure?", the accepted answer states 50 bits is the minimum signature length. 50 bits equal 6.25 bytes, so a signature with 7 bytes (or 7 characters) should have acceptable security. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33044/what-asymetric-scheme-provides-the-shortest-signature-while-being-secure

Comment: @Florent: the accepted answer does not say that at all, in fact the very beginning of the answer states categorically that "You cannot have a secure signature scheme in less than 50 bits.". It describes a signature scheme called BLS that has "... signatures of size 160 to 200 bits at least." I doubt you'll find many implementations of this scheme.

Comment: No, the question asked for a 50 bit signature and the answer was that it is not possible. read the full answer later it says that you need 250-500 Bits. Please read the last table presented here: https://www.keylength.com/en/4/ for the minimum secure key length, e.g. Elliptic Curve

Comment: Thanks for you remarks and link. I assume have no choice but to use a different server to store the signatures.